# How to set textview from sharedprefs

Tags: java, android

```
@Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_device_id);

    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("A4APrefs",1);
    int PairId = settings.getInt("CON_ID", 000000); 

    TextView t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtPairId);
    t.setText(PairId);

}
```

What is wrong with this code? can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This

```
t.setText(PairId);
```

will look for a `resource` with `id` equal to the value of `PairId`

Try instead

```
t.setText(String.valueOf(PairId));  // get the String value
```

[setText(int res)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText%28int%29)

If this doesn't fix your problem, please be specific about what doesn't work in your code

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked, mind helping me on something else as well?

Comment: I don't mind at all...that's half of the reason I'm a SO member. If its something simple and related I can help you here. Otherwise you should post a new question with relevant code and error messages